# How to recognise a PDF to be from a number of predefined layouts/templates?

Tags: python, templates, pdf, layout, extract

I'm currently working on a project in which we want to give users the ability to upload a pdf and store it in their account. On our backend, we then want to scan the pdf, see if it matches one of our predefined (to be done) templates, and then extract the information from the pdf (such as name, date and a QR-code).

The main challenge we're facing here is to be able to define templates and have the server recognise the pdf to be one of the templates. I know that PDF is an open specification, but I don't know if there are any implementations suitable for this kind of use. I searched around but I couldn't really find anything suitable.

So my question; does anybody know of an implementation which we can use for predefining templates, recognising pdf's to be one of the templates, and extracting the relevant information from it? The implementation can be either open source or commercial and in any language (Python, Java, php, whatever..), as long as I can somehow use it from the command line or import it as a library in a project.

All tips are welcome!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: How are your users using your templates? Are those templates PDF forms and the users only fill them in? Do they have some PDF editing tool and add their own contents using that? Or do they probably even print the PDF, scan it, edit that image and wrap it in a PDF again?

Comment: @mkl - Our users will not use the templates. The idea is that there are external parties organising events. For these events they give out tickets in PDF. Users of our service should be able to upload the pdf and our service should then recognise which event the pdf is for. To achieve this, I figured we need to define each and every PDF  in a sort of template, so that our pdfRecognizer() function (or something like that) can actually recognise for which even the pdf is. So users don't edit the PDF, they just upload and we need to recognise it automatically. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, i don't know ready-to-use solutions for that. I would assume, though, that each organize puts his logo at a fixed position of the pdf. You could render the pdf as image and compare the respective area with an existing image of the respective organizer logo. Having recognized the organizer like this you can extract Text from the pdf at the positions in the pdf typical for that organizer. Thus, you'd need a PDF library allowing to render PDFs as images and to extract Text. Furthermore you need some image comparison function.